# Update Android Application Without Google Play

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

I'm facing a problem where i have a set of apps that are used by people on my company, these apps are not standalone apps, they need an app launcher (an app that calls another apps passing some data to them).

The data that the app launcher passes is the user session and settings, the app that the launcher opens needs this data to work, if i try to open these apps outside the launcher it will trigger a "No user session found" error, that is intended for security reasons.

The launcher also looks into our server for updates, if an app has a newer version the launcher will download it and ask for the user to uninstall the app that it needs update and will also will ask to install the updated version of the app... This is painful because we have many apps and the user needs to pay attention to accept the uninstall and installation message.

1 - Is there a way to update our apps **using our launcher** without asking the user for permission ?

2 - Is there a way to update the apps downloading only a small patch **instead of the full apk** ?

3 - In this scenario what would you guys propose to resolve this issue ?

I hope that i made the problem clear, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. `Is there a way to update our apps using our launcher` no unfortunately. No 3rd-party app can install/uninstall another 3rd-party app in a normal usage scenario. Exception is having root access, the launcher app being a system app, or the launcher app being set as device admin app.
2. `Is there a way to update the apps downloading only a small patch instead of the full apk` not the way you likely think it is, but there is such way. You can use dynamic class loading. This basically enables you to download executable code, and call calsses and methods via interfaces, or via reflection. [More info](https://link.medium.com/uukG8UDiw0).
3. `what would you guys propose` if that was me who needed this, I'd use dynamic class loading, or device admin app depending on what exactly and how exactly your launcher and apps work.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, in any of these scenarios can i install the downloaded application or uninstall a app without asking permission to the user ?

Comment: `having root access, the launcher app being a system app, or the launcher app being set as device admin app.`